# Should One Reuse a Facebook Token or Reuse a Facebook Session when Browser is Redirected to a New Page?

Tags: facebook, session, web, token

In using facebook sessions to interface from a website with a user's facebook data, when should one preserve a facebook session and when should one preserve a facebook token?

After a facebook session is established on a particular page and the browser is redirected to a new page should the session be saved and reused or should the facebook token be saved and a new facebook session created from that facebook token?

This?

```
$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
```

Or this?

```
$token = $_SESSION['session']->getToken();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your app's environment (canvas, website, etc), so I'm doing a lot of assuming but...

I only use canvas apps and for the most part the PHP SDK will handle all that for you when set up correctly (for instance if the user opens a new tab from within your app).  If you need to make a request to another page without any login flow (like what you're asking), I just save the access token and create a session from there.  Every time a user logs into my app I save their access token to my database.  While they are using my app, I can use that access token on to make calls to pages user's don't interact with but still get their FB info that I need.  After a while that token expires, but while a user is interacting with my app I don't need to worry about them expiring as I will acquire a new token once they log in again at some future point in time.

So just save the token and match it with a user ID.  Then use that token to create a session where you need it.  If you need to interact with information far beyond when a user has logged out of your app, you might need the extended life access tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending